# nodejs binding an object in callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Here is what I have tried.

```
var obj = {sfsf: fsdfs};
connection.query("UPDATE table SET `qty` = `qty` - ? WHERE item_id = ?", [p1, p2], callback.bind(obj))
```

Callback function:

```
function callback(f_err, f_rows, f_fields){ //default parameters err, rows, fields
    if(!f_err){
        console.log(obj); //undefined
        // other lines of code
    }
}
```

I have a doubt that I'm doing it in a wrong way. There are default parameters that get passed after query execution like `err, rows, fields`. with those parameters, I want to pass some data to the callback function. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small citation

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So, in your case in callback `obj` bind as `this`. So you must to change `console.log(obj)` to `console.log(this)`.
You can find more info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)